# SQL how to avoid duplicate insert in a table

Tags: sql

how to avoid duplicate insert in a table? I use below query to insert in to table:

```
insert into RefundDetails(ID,StatusModified,RefundAmount,OrderNumber) 
  select O.id,O.StatusModified,OI.RefundAmount,O.OrderNumber 
  from Monsoon.dbo.[Order] as O  
  WITH (NOLOCK) JOIN Monsoon.dbo.OrderItem as OI  
  WITH (NOLOCK)on O.Id = OI.OrderId 
  WHERE o.ID in (SELECT OrderID 
                 FROM Mon2QB.dbo.monQB_OrderActivityView 
                 WHERE ACTIVITYTYPE = 4 AND at BETWEEN '10/30/2012' AND '11/3/2012') AND (O.StatusModified < '11/3/2012')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the DISTINCT keyword to remove duplicates from your select statement

```
insert into RefundDetails
(ID,StatusModified,RefundAmount,OrderNumber) 
select distinct
 O.id
,O.StatusModified
,OI.RefundAmount
,O.OrderNumber 
from Monsoon.dbo.[Order] as O WITH (NOLOCK) 
JOIN Monsoon.dbo.OrderItem as OI WITH (NOLOCK)
    on O.Id = OI.OrderId 
WHERE o.ID in 
(
    SELECT OrderID 
    FROM Mon2QB.dbo.monQB_OrderActivityView 
    WHERE ACTIVITYTYPE = 4 
    AND at BETWEEN '10/30/2012' AND '11/3/2012'
) 
AND O.StatusModified < '11/3/2012'
```

or if you're concerned that the table already contains some value, specify to only insert where the new entry's not already in there:

```
insert into RefundDetails
(ID,StatusModified,RefundAmount,OrderNumber) 
select distinct
 O.id
,O.StatusModified
,OI.RefundAmount
,O.OrderNumber 
from Monsoon.dbo.[Order] as O WITH (NOLOCK) 
JOIN Monsoon.dbo.OrderItem as OI WITH (NOLOCK)
    on O.Id = OI.OrderId 
WHERE o.ID in 
(
    SELECT OrderID 
    FROM Mon2QB.dbo.monQB_OrderActivityView 
    WHERE ACTIVITYTYPE = 4 
    AND at BETWEEN '10/30/2012' AND '11/3/2012'
) 
AND O.StatusModified < '11/3/2012'

--assuming we just need to check o.id to determine a duplicate:
and O.id not in 
(
    select o.id
    from RefundDetails
)

--alternatively, if the entire record counts as a duplicate
and not exists
(
    select top 1 1 
    from RefundDetails b
    where O.id = b.id
    and O.StatusModified = b.StatusModified
    and OI.RefundAmount = b.RefundAmound
    and O.OrderNumber = b.Order Number
```

Finally, if you want something more advanced (i.e. to allow you to insert new orders and update existing ones), and if you're using SQL or Oracle, you have the MERGE statement: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/28/sql-server-2008-introduction-to-merge-statement-one-statement-for-insert-update-delete/

Answer (score 1):

You may create the procedure to insert the value into the table.

```
create procedure p_insert_tablename
columname datatype,
coluname datatype
begin
if exists(select 1 from tblname where [give the condition on which you cols value you dont want the duplicate value])
/*if true then update the value by update query using the condition */
/*dont forget to give condition in update query*/

else

/*insert the value*/
exit
```

To call procedure

```
exec p_insert_tablename col1, col2,...
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the db your using but aren't you looking for something like rownum < 2 which returns the topmost row?

Answer (score 0):

```
To ignore (with a warning) attempts to insert duplicate keys rather than raising an error and having the whole statement fail you can use the IGNORE_DUP_KEY option.

  CREATE TABLE RefundDetails
  (
   ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON),
   ...
   --your columns  
   )
```